# How to refactor method to accept generic type as its argument in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, refactoring

I have a bunch of methods that create same result type ,but their parameter type varies.Assume `int` is the result type ,and `bool`,`int`,`float`,etc,etc,
and prototype are like this:

```
int method1(int param1);
int method2(bool param1);
int method3(float param1);
```

how can I refactor them to looks like this:

```
int methodGenericVersion1<T>(T arg1);
```

By the way ,I cannot see the implementation of those non-generic methods.

**EDIT**

I want to invoke like this:

```
methodGenericVersion1<int>(param1);
methodGenericVersion1<bool>(param1);
methodGenericVersion1<float>(param1);
```

Comment: If you can't see (and presumably change) code for the method what do you expect from making something generic? Show sample code you have and what approximately you want to achieve...

Comment: This will only be beneficial if all three methods have the same code. The normal reason for having separate methods with different arguments is so you can have different logic for different inputs.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Dispatch them in a single method like the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to dispatch to the 'correct' method based on the actual generic type, like so:

```
public int GenericMethod<T>(T t)
{
    if (t is int)
    {
        return method1(t as int);
    }
    else if (t is bool)
    {
        return method2(t as bool);
    }
    else if (t is float)
    {
        return method3(t as float);
    }
    ...

    throw new ArgumentInvalidException(...);
}
```

However, if the goal is to provide a "single method" that can be used polymorphically across a limited range of types, then I question why a generic is necessary.  You can use method overloading and get exactly the same developer experience, like so:

```
public int method(int arg)
{
     return method1(arg);
}

public int method(bool arg)
{
     return method2(arg);
}

public int method(float arg)
{
      return method3(arg);
}
```

Comment: It seems like that I have violate the rule of using **generic**.

Comment: your first solution is what I want,the reason I want that version is that I encounter a situation that constantly change the type of the argument,but the argument are scattered all around,and other unknown method may depend on that type of argument.

Comment: My first solution was supposed to be a counterexample.  The reason is that when you write a generic method, it should work with any type that meets the generic parameter constraints placed on the generic type parameter.  Otherwise, the generic method is misleading:  Its type signature says it can accept a type, but it doesn't follow that promise.

Comment: the problem has changed to another one which has something to do with [dynamic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739078/assignment-to-struct-array-inside-method-does-not-work-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

You are so close.Just you need to specify generic parameter within the method name like this:

```
int methodGenericVersion1<T>(T arg1)
```

Also you might want to add a `struct` constraint if you want to pass value types only:

```
int methodGenericVersion1<T>(T arg1) where T : struct
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
int Test<T>(T v)
{
    return -1;
}
```